# How can I find $f(3)$ if $f(2x)=f^2(x)-2f(x)-\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations

If $f(2x)=f^2(x)-2f(x)-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(1) = 2$ then find $f(3)$.

Can you give me any hint that I can start with?

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: Question was just like this. Idk if it is continous or not

Comment: If it is not, then $f(3)$ can be just about anything.

Comment: It appears as if the data is not sufficient to compute $f(3)$

Comment: How can we solve if it is continous?

Comment: i ended up finding $f(2)=-1/2$.

Comment: My gut reaction is to run the recurrence backward to zero (in the limit), and then have an explicit expression for $f(0)$ in terms of $f(3)$; but $f(0)$ can be determined independently (well, the quadratic formula gives two answers; maybe one of them can be eliminated logically). But the issue with this is that we have a choice of $\pm$ at each step, and eliminating *all* of those choices seems unlikely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(2x)=f^2(x)-2f(x)-\frac{1}{2}
$
and
$f(1) = 2
$.

I can see how to get
$f(2^n)$
and expressions for
$f(2^{-n})$,
but I don't see how to get
$f(3)$.

I show what I've got so far.
All fairly trivial.

$f(2x)+\frac32
=f^2(x)-2f(x)+1
=(f(x)-1)^2
$
so
$f(x)
=1\pm\sqrt{f(2x)+\frac32}
$.

$x = 0
\implies f(0) = f^2(0)-2f(0)-\frac12
$
or
$f^2(0)-3f(0) = \frac12
$
or
$f^2(0)-3f(0)+9/4 
=\frac12+9/4
=\frac{11}{4}
$
or
$(f(0)-\frac32)^2 
=\frac{11}{4}
$
or
$f(0)
=\frac32\pm\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}
$.

$x=1
\implies f(2) = -\frac12
$.

$x=\frac12
\implies f(\frac12) = 1\pm\sqrt{f(1)+\frac32}
=1\pm\sqrt{\frac72}
$.

And that's all.